# How can I get this query to print a record that only exists in one table?

Tags: sql, database, select, sql-scripts

I am trying to create a query that will accept a date from the user and display information from two tables based on this date.  This works for all of my tests except my last test.  My last test, I enter a date that should return a record that only exists in the expmast table and does not exist in the expbycc table.  When I enter the date to try and get this record to be returned, it tells me no records have been found.  I know this is because in my where, i have an AND  that checks if M.ExpNum = C.ExpNUm which isn;t true for this record because it only exists in one table.  I can not figure out how to get this query to work.  Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.  Below is my script, followed by the table structures used for this query, thank you.

Script:

```
ACCEPT Date PROMPT 'Enter a date:';

SELECT M.ExpNum, EDate, IsCash, StoreCode, CashAmt, CType, CCNum, Amt
FROM ExpMast M, ExpByCc C
WHERE EDate = to_date('&Date','mm-dd-yy')
AND M.ExpNum = C.ExpNum;
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EXPMAST
   (ExpNum NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EDate DATE,
    IsCash VARCHAR2(1),
    StoreCode VARCHAR2(4),
    CONSTRAINT fk_STORE_EXPMAST FOREIGN KEY (StoreCode)
    REFERENCES STORE (Code)
);


CREATE TABLE ExpByCC
   (ExpNum NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
    CType VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    CCNum VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
    Amt DECIMAL(5,2),
    CONSTRAINT fk_CRCARD_ExpByCC FOREIGN KEY (CType, CCNum)
    REFERENCES CRCARD (CType, CCNum),
    CONSTRAINT fk_EXPMAST_ExpByCC FOREIGN KEY (ExpNum)
    REFERENCES EXPMAST (ExpNum),
    CONSTRAINT pk_ExpByCC PRIMARY KEY (ExpNum, CType, CCNum)
);
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `left outer join`.  And you can't express an outer join using your implicit `join` syntax.  You want to use explicit joins in the `from` clause.

A simple rule:  NEVER use commas in the `from` clause.

Now, it is easy:

```
SELECT M.ExpNum, EDate, IsCash, StoreCode, CashAmt, CType, CCNum, Amt
FROM ExpMast M LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ExpByCc C
     ON M.ExpNum = C.ExpNum AND
WHERE M.EDate = to_date('&Date','mm-dd-yy') AND
      C.ExpNum IS NULL;
```

Comment: teacher isn't really doing a good job with teaching the joins.  I had a db class at penn state when I was there and knew we used them but for what ever reason my teacher at my current college is doing it the way I had it so I was trying that way.  Thank you though for the advice I am going to change my script and hopefully it works.  Thanks again

Comment: @user3255899 . . . I'm sorry you have a teach who gives poor advice.  You, alas, are not the only one.

Comment: As @Gordon says, use the `JOIN..ON..` style.